# Jquery Autocomplete and MySQL ID Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

hoping someone can help me out with something.
I've got a piece of code which allows the Jquery Autocomplete. What I'm wanting to do is to use the ID(primary key) from my MySQL table and then use that to POST on to another screen.

How would I go about getting the ID into a hidden value from the Jquery code?

Here are my snippets.

Jquery

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'JQUERYTEST.php'
    });
});
</script>
```

Html

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="shop">Shopname: </label>
    <input id="shop">
</div>
```

Php/MySQL

```
<?php
    //database configuration
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'aurora';

    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shopname LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['shopname'] . ' - '. $row['streetaddress'] . ' - ' . $row['postcode'];
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to return a json_encoded assoc array like so:

`while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array('value'=>$row['id'], 'label' => $row['shopname'] . ' - '. $row['streetaddress'] . ' - ' . $row['postcode']);
    }`

Comment: Thanks, but what would I need to change to my Jquery code?

Comment: nothing :-) It should just work and the autocomplete jquery plugin would build a proper value/label list

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you will have to use an Ajax call to get the data from the server. So, change your autocomplete function and add an ajax call to receive a response. Then you will have to loop the JSON array in jquery. I have created the id as the whole string with `shopname`, `streetaddress` and `postcode`. Currently, your code doesn't inserts the `ID` parameter from the database. You can create an id depending on your needs. Then dynamically I have created the HTML and then placed it inside the `<div class="ui-widget">`

```
 <script>
 $( function() {
    $( "#skills" ).autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "search.php",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          data: {
            term: request.term
          },
          success: function( data ) {
             var html = "";
             $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                  var arr = item.split('-');
                  html += "<label for='shop'>Shopname:"+arr[0]+" </label><input id='"+item+"' type='hidden'><br>";
             });​ 

             $('.ui-widget').html(html);

          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Try this out. I hope this helps you.